# Designing a wireless network of sensors

Tags: sensor, wireless, network

I'm designing a network of wireless sensors for an outdoor enviroment. It will consist of aprox. 30 sensors powered by battery (6 months autonomy), taking measurements with a low frequncy (max 10 times per day), distributed in a radius of 100m, with a central node as a gateway. The gateway will be powered by battery and solar panel.

- What is the recommended communication protocol to cover a radius of 100m, star topology, in an outdoor environment (farm) and with the nodes being powered by battery? I think LoRa is for larger areas and ZigBee for smaller areas.
- How do I estimate the solar panel and the battery capacity, once I have the total power consumption, for the gateway?. I think that the solar panel must provide enough energy to power the station during the day, plus the energy to recharge the battery. What about cloudy days?. Is there a rule of thumb for this?.
- The gateway will be always listening for new communications, but the nodes will be 99.9% of the time in sleep mode, so all the communications must be initiated by the nodes. Is there a way for the gateway to wakeup the nodes using a wireless signal and start the communication? Or the only way would be to wakeup the nodes periodically with an internal RTC and poll the gateway for new messages?
- The power consumption of the communication module of the gateway in "listening" mode is the same as the Rx power consumption specified in the datasheets? Or the Rx power consumption is for when the module is actually receiving data?

Comment: Take a look on Z-Wave.

Comment: Zigbee, Z-Wave, LoRa doesn't matter for distance.  Those are for data topologies (Mesh, Star, etc.).  Distance from node to node is all about Tx power and RX sensitivity.

Comment: If the nodes are asleep, then they are not listening.  They have to wake up and listen for data with their address.

Comment: Range, Power use, Speed, Size, Security ,Cost . Pick any 4.

Comment: Looks like the LoRa spec has really good sensitivity and decent power output without adding amplifiers. https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2017/jun/develop-lora-for-low-rate-long-range-iot-applications  receiver sensitivity of -146 dBm, integrated +18.5(dBm) output

Comment: Reminds me of a 2 way network we  had 25 yrs ago using 1 million IR/RF sensors sharing 6kHz of BW in 928 MHz ISM Band with tie-in >owners database for real-time data collector promoted above TDM daily data. Including all the cell repeaters in a city with head-end S/W interface had to sell for $75 per node to survive that was working at $100 /node . Ended up being sold to biggest competitor Itron who hasn't been able to make it cost-effective so they have meter-readers walk during or drive around homes at night to read  data monthly.  Except now you just want a local PAN for ? $ , ? mW ?secure.

Comment: If you transmit only from the battery equipment and keep number of transmissions low whilst observing a semi random Inter-transmit pause time You’ll probably do yourself a big favour and make battery life years. A radius of whatever distance has nothing to do with protocol.

Comment: IoT developers need to learn to write good specs. for the 5 fundamental tradeoffs and don't underestimate security.

Comment: So, if I want a star topology of 30 nodes, ultra low power consumption, what's the recommended protocol? Any recommended module that meet the distance requirementes?